# Calculate an orthogonal matrix that maps a matrix $X$ to $Y$

Tags: linear-algebra

Here $X,Y \in {\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}}$ and we want to find an orthogonal matrix $A \in {\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}$ such that $AX=Y$. There may be multiple solutions, and any one will be OK. Also there may be no solutions. Is there some general methods to solve this question?

Comment: You want to compute the singular value decompositions of $X$ and $Y$. Then a solution exists iff $X$ and $Y$ have the same nonzero singular values with the same right singular vectors, and the left singular vectors tell you how to compute $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is an orthogonal matrix it preserves inner products. So I think a necessary and sufficient condition for at least one solution is that the inner product of each pair of columns in $X$ (considered as vectors) is the same as the inner product of the corresponding pair of columns in $Y$.

If the columns of $X$ (considered as vectors) do not span $\mathbb{R}^n$ then there may be more than one solution. For example if

$X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$

$Y = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$

then there are two solutions (one rotation and one reflection):

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

and

$A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$